# Generator, Selector Pattern to calculate approximations in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a generator, selector pattern to approximately calculate square roots in haskell

My generator looks like this:

```
generator :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> [Double]
generator f a           = generator f (f a)
```

My selector:

```
selector :: Double -> [Double] -> Double
selector eps (a : b : r)
  | abs(a - b) <= eps   = b
  | otherwise           = selector eps (b : r)
```

And the approx function:

```
next :: Double -> Double -> Double
next n x                = (x + n/x) / 2
```

Calling this like `selector 0.1 (generator (next 5) 2)`
should give me `...(next 5( next 5 (next 5 2)))` so `[2.25, 2.23611111111111, 2.2360679779158,...]` since my eps parameter is 0.1 `abs(a - b) <= eps` should be true on the first execution giving me `2.23611111111111` as a result. I do however end in a endless loop.

Could somebody explain to me what is wrong in the implementation of those functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you'd omit the type signature, you'd get `generator :: (a -> a) -> a -> b`, which could serve as a valuable hint. So maybe there's a value in *not* providing the signatures yourself, or at least temporarily removing them, as a debugging / development  technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition

```
generator f a = generator f (f a)
```

never generates any list elements: it gets stuck into an infinite recursion instead. You probably want

```
generator f a = a : generator f (f a)
```

which makes `a` to be the first element, followed by all the others we generate using recursion.

It could also be beneficial to avoid putting unevaluated thunks in the list. To avoid that, one could use

```
generator f a = a `seq` (a : generator f (f a))
```

so that `a` is evaluated early. This should not matter much in your code, since the 
selector immediately evaluates the thunks as soon as they are generated.

Answer (score 3):

Your generator function is missing the `a:`, as [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55431323/7509065) correctly points out. However, there's a better solution than just adding that. Get rid of `generator` altogether, and use the built-in method [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) instead (or [`iterate'` from Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:iterate-39-) if you want to avoid unevaluated thunks). These methods have the same behavior that you want from `generate`, but support optimizations like [list fusion](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.4/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#list-fusion) that your own method won't. And of course, there's also the advantage that it's one less function that you have to write and maintain.

Comment: and next ;) get rid of `selector`, and just use `until` so no list fusion is even needed... :)